# Spring Boot & MongoDB, Query nested map for key

Tags: json, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to query MongoDB for all documents that have a specific key inside a document's nested map

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5a5cd9711736c32c45f11adf"),
   "name" : "Test A",
   "userSubscription" : {
      "map" : {
          "1234" : true,
          "999" : true,
      }
   }
}
```

I'm querying as follows:

```
db.getCollection('myColl').find( { "userSubscription.map" : {"1234":true }})
```

It's working, **but**, it return only documents that holds a single value of "1234", So if "userSubscription.map" contains "1234" **and** "5555" the query not showing any results.

I'm using Robo3T to test queries, and SpringBoot annotations to query this,
Can the answer be in Spring Boot annotation query?

Spring Boot query example:

```
@Query("{QUERY : ?0}")
List<Person> findByUserSubscription(String key);
```

** The "?0" is to use the first method param

Thanks!!!

**UPDATE:**

Now the document looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a5cd9711736c32c45f11adf"),
   "name" : "Test A",    
   "userSubscription" : {
      "1234" : true,
      "3333" : true
    }
}
```

Robo 3T Query: `db.getCollection('Person').find({ "userSubscription.1234": {$exists : true} })`

Works PERFECT!

But, The query in Spring boot looks like:

```
@Query("{userSubscription.?0 : {$exists: true} }")
```

and it doesn't show any results...

What is the problem???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Model the map as [array of embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/) like

```
{
  "map" : [
     {k: "1234", v: true},
     {k: "999", v: true}
  ]
}
```

and you can find by key

```
db.myColl.find({"userSubscription.map":{$elemMatch: { k: "1234", v: true } } })
```

and

```
@Query("{'userSubscription.map':{$elemMatch: { k: ?0, v: true } } }")
List<Person> findByUserSubscription(String key);
```

`

Comment: I'm failing to understand how to achieve this structure from the java code

Comment: You have to run update to move to new structure before you can query. Is that what you doing ? [`Here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210608/mongodb-convert-multiple-objects-to-an-array-in-place-permanently/48211208#48211208) is one such example. You have to run aggregation if you updating to new strucutre is not an option for you.

Comment: It's not a live DB so I can drop the collection. 
I don't understand how this structure is represented in Java code.
userSubscription is now an Array of Map object with key & value?

Comment: It's not a live DB so I can drop the collection. 
I don't understand how this structure is represented in Java code.
userSubscription is now an Array of Map object with key & value?

The whole idea is not to iterate over the whole array, therefore the map so I can use put and the keys will be unique...

Comment: I agree with your approach but mongodb cant query the structure with the way you have. The equivalent mongodb strucure is array of embedded documents. So to model this in java you can use `List<Map<String, Object>>`. No iteration is required as the direct key lookup is performed to server side. You have to use aggregation query if you like to keep your structure which is in essence transforms it to mongo db structure in aggregation pipeline before querying

Comment: Very well, trying now! :)

Comment: It's Working! Thanks! :)

Comment: I did realize that too when answering your question. Spring for some reasons transforms this to `@Query("{userSubscription.\"1234\" : {$exists: true} }")` which is not correct. So it looks like it is not supported. One more reason to have the documents as array of embedded documents.

Comment: Exactly that's the problem... Well, I'll do that.. bummer

THANKS for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

You missed single quote for @Query.

```java
@Query("{'userSubscription.?0' : {$exists: true} }")
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a more simple solution with using Query and Criteria Class in Spring Data mongodb. like below:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("userSubscription."+key).exists(true));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, YourDocument.class);
```