# How to update mongodb object to change array of key-value in pure array?

Tags: mongodb

I have saved in each document in MongoDB a fiel called "track". Inside each one there is an object with keys such as '0', '1', and so on. I have to replace this part with an array.

Actual situation

```
"track" : {
                "0" : {
                        "name" : "Crossdromo A",
                        "type" : "Motocross"
                },
                "1" : {
                        "name" : "Crossdromo B",
                        "type" : "Minicross"
                }
        }
```

Desiderata

```
"track" : [
                {
                        "name" : "Crossdromo A",
                        "type" : "Motocross"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Crossdromo B",
                        "type" : "Minicross"
                }
        ]
```

Any suggestions on how to change this?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48210608/2683814

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/):

```
db.getCollection('samples').aggregate([{ //Replace 'samples' with your collection name
    $match: {} //You can change this to any query if you don't want to apply it to all documents in the collection
},
{
    $addFields: {
        track: {
            $objectToArray: '$track'  //This converts it to [{k: '0', v: { "name" : "Crossdromo A", "type" : "Motocross" }}, {k: 1,..]
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        track: '$track.v' //This pulls the 'v' key  from the previous object.
    }
}, {
    $out: 'samples' //Replace 'samples' with your collection name   
}])
```